# Is there a best practices/example solution for using the Fb C# SDK v6 on ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm currently using the Fb C# SDK v5, works like a champ. Migrating to v6 is proving more challenging than I had anticipated.

So, I decided to rewrite the auth code from scratch. Is this the bare minimum needed to authenticate a user?

1. Use the Fb js sdk to set the appId, subscribe to the auth event
2. Subscribe to the Fb.UI auth event, pass the access token to the server
3. Once the server has the access token, query the graph

In v5 I was doing this in an OnActionExecuting override, checking against an active session (if it wasn't active, I'd re-auth via Fb). I just can't seem to get it to work like that on v6.

Is there a best practices, or example solution, for using the Fb C# SDK v6 on ASP.NET MVC? I'd like to make sure I'm doing this right. I've found a couple resources, but they don't look like they're specifically for ASP.NET MVC:

1. [Writing your First Facebook Application (v6)](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx)
2. [Getting Started with the Facebook C# SDK for ASP.NET](http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for the same and now I found a sample for MVC and Facebook v6.0 api at github:
https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-aspnet-sample